# Next.js routing from "pages/[...slug].js" not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is how my pages folder looks like:

```
pages
   index.js  
   [...slug].js
```

I know that the problem lies for sure in the fact that I am using catch all routes directly in the **pages** folder, because I tried with a "pages/page/[...slug].js structure and everything works fine.

When navigating using the Link component from the index.js page to a [...slug].js page (e.g. /careers or /blog), **everything works fine**.

**BUT** when navigating from a [...slug].js page (e.g. /contact) to another similar page (e.g. /blog) only the URL changes correctly, but **the content of the page stays the same**, so there is no rerendering.

Note: Navigating from a [...slug].js page back to the root file (href="/") works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR:
When returning the set of props from your getStaticProps or getServerSideProps function, return a "key" prop and assign it a unique value, so that react is able to differentiate between the two pages that are served from the same dynamic path.

I found the solution to the "problem" in github issue from last year: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9992

You can find a clear solution reading through the issue I linked.

Comment: I don't know why this answer received downvotes. It works and the link provided is super helpful. Just adding to this answer that you can instead do `<Component {...pageProps} key={router.asPath} />` in the `_app.js` component to overcome the issue. The explanation is found in the provided link.

Answer (score -3):

Make each page its own file within your pages folder. For example, you could have:

```
pages/
  index.js
  contact.js
  careers.js
  blog.js
```

Each file should export a default function that returns JSX.